# Error when launching 'rethinkdb-restore': No such file or director

Tags: rethinkdb

I am importing DB backup moved on AWS server from my local system

While restoring rethink db using command :

**rethinkdb restore /home/league_ally/rethinkexport.tar.gz**

Following error is coming:

```
Error when launching 'rethinkdb-restore': No such file or directory
The rethinkdb-restore command depends on the RethinkDB Python driver,    
which must be installed.
If the Python driver is already installed, make sure that the PATH 
environment variable
includes the location of the backup scripts, and that the current  
user has permission to
access and run the scripts.
Instructions for installing the RethinkDB Python driver are available  
here:
http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install-drivers/python/
```

Comment: So, install python driver from here http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install-drivers/python/

Comment: i have installed python driver, but still it's giving this error

Comment: Try `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem while restoring the data in my app. I found that PIP needs to be upgrade. After upgrading PIP I was able to restore my database

Answer (score 6):

As you've already done, the first step is to install the `rethinkdb` Python package. For example:

```
$ pip install rethinkdb
```

Then, if you still see the following error:

```
$ rethinkdb-restore
Error when launching 'rethinkdb-restore': No such file or directory
```

Try running it as:

```
$ python -mrethinkdb._restore
Usage: rethinkdb restore FILE [-c HOST:PORT] ...
```

Comment: The last script works for me 
```python -mrethinkdb._restore FILE```

Thanks